# Laravel 5.4: Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Actually, my question is very simple but I couldn't find any answer.

I'm using Laravel eloquent, I have 3 tables:

```
company_types
-id
-name

document_types
-id
-name
```

and a pivot table called:

```
company_type_document_type
-company_type_id
-document_type_id
-is_default
```

I already have the `company_type_id` from my company object and I'm trying to get the `name` of the `document_type`
like this:

```
controller...
$document_type = CompanyTypesDocumentTypes::where('company_type_id',$company->company_type_id)->with('document_type')->where('is_default',true)->first();

view...
{{ $document_type->name }}
```

I'm sure that the problem is with my models, but the issue is that I don't really understand when to user "hasMany" or "BelongsToMany" etc...
In Addition, I think that there might be a problem with the name of the pivot table cause there are too many underscores

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's many-to-many, you should use [`wherePivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method.

Define the relationship:

```
public function defaultDocumentTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(DocumentType::class)->wherePivot('is_default', 1);
}
```

Then you can get document types using this relationship:

```
$companyType = CompanyType::find($companyTypeId);
$documentTypes = $companyType->defaultDocumentTypes()->get();
```

Display them in the view:

```
@foreach ($documentTypes as $documentType)
    {{ $documentType->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: where should i define the relationship? it seems like you defined in inside the CompanyType model, but i can't call the model inside the model

Comment: I changed the name of the table to company_type_document_type ( it was company_types_document_types and i forgot to write it in the question ) and i also change this line:    `return $this->belongsToMany(DocumntType::class)->wherePivot('is_default', 1);`
 to this:    `return $this->belongsToMany(CompanyType::class)->wherePivot('is_default', 1);`

Comment: It should be defined in the `CompanyType` model, but it should return `DocumentType` relationship:  `return $this->belongsToMany(DocumentType::class)->wherePivot('is_def‌​ault', 1);`